# Can you change which fields align with which in an Embed using Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How can you make two embed fields in line with each other, then two more in line with each other below that. My problem now is that I have 4 fields, and I want two on the top and two on the bottom.

By setting the `inline` parameter of the `Embed.add_field()` method to True, it doesn't allow anything else on that line. However, by making them all False, it results in this:

[image: My problem now]

Ideally, in reference to the above image, I would like Start Date and Start Time in line with each other, then End Date and End Time in line with each other. End Date and End Time should be placed where End Time currently sits in the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's only one way to do it, by using zero-width character (`\u200b`) as a field name and value.

```
embed.add_field(name="ONE", value="ONE", inline=True)
embed.add_field(name="TWO", value="TWO", inline=True)
embed.add_field(name=u"\u200b", value=u"\u200b", inline=True/False)
embed.add_field(name="THREE", value="THREE", inline=True)
embed.add_field(name="FOUR", value="FOUR", inline=True)
```